# Is there a way to batch MySQL select statements and return the total dataset?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, aggregation

I have a use case where I have a customer table which joins with a couple of other tables. It’s a many to one relationship so joining with these two tables will result in over 100+ rows for each customer. The SELECT statement with over 10000 customers doesn’t perform well.

I was wondering if there is a way to loop over each customer, append the result of the SELECT statement and then provide the output in a MySQL stored procedure. This can be done using a CURSOR and a temporary table but is there a way to do it without a temporary table?

Comment: This sounds like a data warehousing problem. What's wrong with making a secondary reporting table?

Comment: I think the temp table is the only way. You can have multiple `SELECT` queries in the procedure, but that will create multiple result sets, and the calling application will have to loop over them to get all the results.